# How can we implement JWE with just nodejs Crypto library?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt, cryptojs, jwe

This is what I am doing to generate JWT tokens for now. How can I generate JWE tokens with just crypto library without using any other npde packages?

```
var Header = {"alg": "HS256","typ": "JWT"},
    Payload = {"content": "valuable data"},
    secret_key = "xxxxx123xxxxxxxx123xxxxxxxx";

function create_jwt(Header, Payload) {

  var encodedString = btoa(JSON.stringify(Header)) + "." + btoa(JSON.stringify(Payload));

  var hmac_hash = z.hmac('sha256', secret_key, encodedString, "base64");
  return console.log(encodedString + "." + hmac_hash);
}
```

Comment: the implementation is described in [rfc7516](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7516)

Comment: Ya but the question is specific to nodejs's built in crypto library. Most algo and enc. options are not present there so wondering if anyone has a approach they've tried.

Comment: in that case, you'll need to implement any missing "algo and enc. options" yourself if you don't want to use any "npde" packages

Comment: You will certainly find help by reading the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47720701/how-to-generate-and-validate-jwe-in-node-js/47919929